# Last query_var not working with rewritten URL

Tags: rewrite-rules, query-variable

I am trying to get custom URLs to load a specific template page, and I am mostly there, but my last `query_var` in the string refuses to load. Here is what is in my functions file:

```
function custom_query_vars_filter($vars) {
  $vars[] = 'issueloc';
  $vars[] .= 'issuearea';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'custom_query_vars_filter' );

function prefix_issues_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule( 'issues/([^/]+)/([^/]+)', 'index.php?ae_issues=$matches[1]&issueloc=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'issues/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)', 'index.php?ae_issues=$matches[1]&issueloc=$matches[2]&issuearea=$matches[3]', 'top' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'prefix_issues_rewrite_rule' );

function prefix_url_rewrite_templates() {

    if ( get_query_var( 'issueloc' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
            return get_template_directory() . '/taxonomy-ae_issues.php';
        });
    }
```

and when I load a page like `mysiteaddress/issues/issueloc/issuearea`, it will correctly load the template I want, and I will be able to pull the `query_var` for `issueloc`. But the `query_var` for `issuearea` is absent from the page.

If (on the other hand) I load a page like `mysiteaddress/issues/issueloc/?issuearea=something`, it will recognize my `issuearea` `query_var` (in addition to the others).

Is there something I am missing here? Why won't the last `query_var` load in the rewritten URL (which does load the correct template)? Is there something wrong with my second rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[] =` not `[] .=` to append to an array.

```
function custom_query_vars_filter($vars) {
  $vars[] = 'ae_issues';
  $vars[] = 'issueloc';
  $vars[] = 'issuearea';
  return $vars;
}
```

Another trick, if you don't want to mess with a query is to change these vars to something like `_issueloc` & `_issuearea`. I found making custom queries as flags is nice for template redirects but not necessary to mess with the main query (unless you require it).

---

### WORKING

An alternate might be to added using `add_rewrite_tag()`.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%ae_issues%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%issueloc%', '([^/]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%issuearea%', '([^/]+)' );

    add_rewrite_rule( '^issues/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)', 'index.php?ae_issues=$matches[1]&issueloc=$matches[2]&issuearea=$matches[3]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^issues/([^/]+)/([^/]+)', 'index.php?ae_issues=$matches[1]&issueloc=$matches[2]', 'top' );
} );

add_filter('template_include', function($template){

    global $wp_query;
    if( isset($wp_query->query_vars['ae_issues'])) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($wp_query->query_vars);
        wp_die();
    }
    return $template;

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but removing the . makes no difference for my problem, it stays exactly the same (even after reloading permalinks)

Comment: This update is working for me. Accessing the vars from the `global $wp_query;`

Comment: That last update got it working ( I think it was the add_rewrite_tags or the changing order of the rewrite rules), thanks!